# QTP/VBScript - Function return value is not passed during the 3rd iteration

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have a function to get data table values for my test, based on the function return value (True or False), I am doing subsequent actions. The function return value is getting passed successfully for the first two runs and it returns a empty value during the 3rd run. The return value of the function is maintained until it comes out of the function.

Please see below the example function call and code. The first two function calls Apple and Orange are working fine. Test is failing for the third functional call Banana.

Call Sample_Function(1,"Apple")

Call Sample_Function(2,"Orange")

Call Sample_Function(3,"Banana")

```
Function Sample_Function(RowId,SearchCriteria)
    Dim DataStatus
    DataStatus = Retrieve_Excel_Data(RowId)
    If DataStatus = True Then 'It returns a empty value during 3rd run
      Msgbox "Sucess"
    Else
      Msgbox "Failed"
    End If
End Function

Function Retrieve_Excel_Data(RowId)
    Dim XlsStatus, Source, Target, RowCount
    XlsStatus = False
    DataTable.AddSheet(Target)  
    DataTable.ImportSheet "C:\a.xls", Source, Target
    RowCount = DataTable.GetSheet(PO_Target_SheetName).GetRowCount
    If RowCount < 1 then
         XlsStatus = True
         Retrieve_Excel_Data = XlsStatus
    Else
         Retrieve_Excel_Data = XlsStatus
    End If
End Function`
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you step through your code on the 3rd run?  If you had `On Error Resume Next` turned on and there was an error executing the `Retrieve_Excel_Data` function on the 3rd attempt, it would cause the calling routine (in this case, `Sample_Function`) to move to the next line of code.  That could result in the variable `DataStatus` not getting populated.